# Angular js syntax analyzer

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create Syntax analyzer in angular js.
I have one textarea. If I write anything like
"Select * from Table". then I want to apply some color to keywords like 
Select in Blue,From in a Red, and Table in another different color.
I have keyword's json for this but unable to understand how to do that with angular js.
So First Question is, Is it possible?
If possible then Is there any directive available for this?

Required a help for above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using angular [`ui-codemirror`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-codemirror) in the past and it's exactly what you want.
It's a based on the [codeMirror](https://github.com/marijnh/CodeMirror) synthax highlighter and it's already wrapped in a directive that you could insert as simple as:

```
<textarea ui-codemirror></textarea>
// or
<div ui-codemirror></div>
// or
<ui-codemirror></ui-codemirror>
```

Here are some online demos where you can see it in action: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-codemirror/

Comment: its working. Now can we modified the colors to it?I don't want red color I want to make it Blue

Comment: You should really just read [the docs](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html). Theming can be easily done with simple css files